# different of setText(CharSequence,TextView.BufferType) and setText(CharSequence)

Tags: java, android

what is difference between `setText(CharSequence, TextView.BufferType)` and `setText(CharSequence)`, and when we should use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setText (CharSequence text)
```

Sets the string value of the TextView. whereas

```
setText (CharSequence text, TextView.BufferType type)
```

Sets the text that this TextView is to display and also sets whether it is stored in a styleable/spannable buffer and whether it is editable.

All BufferType options are:

1. TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE
2. TextView.BufferType.NORMAL
3. TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE

for e.g.

```
myEditText.setText("This is new text from setText with BufferType EDITABLE.",  TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

Comment: I don't think this answer explains much. It just echoes the three possible values' names. An slightly edited version of Manish's answer below combined with devconsole's comment would be much more enlightening.

Comment: @m_katsifarakis please check time of this answer and Manish's answer.

Comment: @GiruBhai of course they were posted almost at the same time, but the comment is directed towards the OP so that he can better select an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the difference from the textview code..

```
  if (type == BufferType.EDITABLE || getKeyListener() != null ||
            needEditableForNotification) {
        createEditorIfNeeded();
        Editable t = mEditableFactory.newEditable(text);
        text = t;
        setFilters(t, mFilters);
        InputMethodManager imm = InputMethodManager.peekInstance();
        if (imm != null) imm.restartInput(this);
    } else if (type == BufferType.SPANNABLE || mMovement != null) {
        text = mSpannableFactory.newSpannable(text);
    } else if (!(text instanceof CharWrapper)) {
        text = TextUtils.stringOrSpannedString(text);
    }
```

If you use plain setText by default it takes the type of TextView.BufferType.NORMAL which basically is either plain string to SpannedString.

Comment: The last sentence is not entirely correct, by default setText calls setText(text, mBufferType). While mBufferType defaults to BufferType.NORMAL it gets set in setText(CharSequence, BufferType) which gets called by the constructor. TLDR: setText defaults to the most recently used buffer type, usually the one the TextView was constructed with.

Comment: I believe this answer's example code, combined with @devconsole's comment and a more comprehensive explanation would be much more useful.

Answer (score 0):

according to the documentation the difference is that  `setText(CharSequence,TextView.BufferType)` also sets whether the text is stored in a styleable/spannable buffer and whether it is editable.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)